# How to set badge on app icon programmatically?

Tags: android, notifications, badge, appicon

I'm trying to set up the badge on app icon if there are some pending notifications. Which works well with the following code in `Android Pie`.

```
notificationBuilder.setNumber(i);
notificationBuilder.setBadgeIconType(NotificationCompat.BADGE_ICON_SMALL);
```

But now I need to show the badge if there are any pending unread notifications in the app. The above badge only appears if the notification is present in the notification bar. And once it's dismissed the badge also disappears which is fine but is there any way we can set up badge depending on a count got from firebase?

Answer (score 2):

To display badge you can use [ShortcutBadger](https://github.com/leolin310148/ShortcutBadger)

> An Android library supports badge notification like iOS in Samsung,
>   LG, Sony and HTC launchers

Comment: This does work but with some limitations, I have already implemented it. But now am dealing with android pie. Finding a solution for it.

Comment: Can this library set badge value without any notification. Means I have to set badge value after that I entered into the application